# Column order of a datagridview from SQL Server database in WinForms using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to make my datagridview show data in descending order (from Z to A) based only on one column (`name`). When the form is loaded, in order to achieve that, I have created a stored procedure with the clause `ORDER BY`:

```sql
CREATE PROC ORDENAR
    @IDCATEGORIA INT,
    @NOMBRE NVARCHAR(30),
    @DESCRIPCION NVARCHAR(256)
AS
    SELECT IDCATEGORIA, NOMBRE 
    FROM clasificacion
    WHERE NOMBRE = @NOMBRE
    ORDER BY NOMBRE DESC;
```

Then in my C# code, I call that stored procedure:

```
public void ordenarcategoria(E_CATEGORIA categoria)
{
    using (var conexion = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conectar"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conexion.Open();

        SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("ORDENAR", conexion);
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRE","");
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDCATEGORIA", 1);
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("DESCRIPCION", "");

        CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conexion.Close();
    }
}
```

I want my datagridview to show data in descending order with a stored procedure in SQL Server.

I am using WinForms, and here's how my datagridview is loaded:

```
public void mostrarbuscar(string buscar)
{
    N_clasificacion objn = new N_clasificacion();
    Tablaclasificacion.DataSource = objn.listandoC(buscar);
     
    Tablaclasificacion.ClearSelection();
}

private void fmrClasificacion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mostrarbuscar("");
    accionestabla();
}
```

`tablaclasificacion` is the name of my DGV

Comment: You are gong to need to bring back the data from the `select` somehow, either with `ExecuteReader` or by using a `DataAdapter`. I don't understand why you need `@IDCATEGORIA` and `@DESCRIPCION` parameters

Comment: How can i do that in code?

Comment: Considering I don't even know whether you are using WinForms or WPF, or something else, and no idea how you would like the DGV loaded, I think that is beyond the scope of this question. It's strange that you have titled it `Column order of a datagridview from sql database C# sql` when I don't see how this code works at all, never mind in the correct order. If you can [edit] and show how you normally add data to the DGV maybe we can answer

Comment: i am using WinForm, and i already edited it so you can see how my DGV is loaded and gets its data

Comment: That doesn't help much, what does `objn.listandoC` do? And why can't you do whatever it does in your new function?

Comment: well its kinda hard to explain: i am using a 3-tier architecture for my program and "objn.listandoC" comes from the business logic -tier, which communicates with the data-tier(the 2nd code block in my post) to get the stored procedures, i edited my post so you can see how the method "mostrarbuscar" is used in the load event of the form.

Comment: Your stored procedure has 3 parameters but only uses 1. Fix that and get rid of the two parameters that are not used. And don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)